# Взаимодействие Pyinstaller и Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Никак не могу конвертировать .py в .exe выдаёт такую ошибку. Что делать? Заранее спасибо.

196 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Алексий\Desktop\for python\cmd\cmd.spec
212 INFO: UPX is not available.
212 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\Users\Алексий\Desktop\for python\cmd']
812 INFO: checking Analysis
833 INFO: checking PYZ
849 INFO: checking PKG
849 INFO: Building because toc changed
849 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) cmd.pkg
Cannot find ('PyQt5\QtCore.pyd', 'C:\Users\Алексий\AppData\Local\pyinstaller\bincache00_py37_64bit\pyqt5\qtcore.pyd', 1, 'b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in *run_module_as_main
"**main**", mod_spec)
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Алексий\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py", line 178, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main*_.py", line 59, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 934, in main
build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 856, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
File "C:\Users\Алексий\Desktop\for python\cmd\cmd.spec", line 43, in 
entitlements_file=None,
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 528, in **init**
entitlements_file=self.entitlements_file
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 218, in **init**
self.**postinit**()
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in **postinit**
self.assemble()
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 309, in assemble
CArchiveWriter(self.name, srctoc + mytoc, pylib_name=pylib_name)
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 313, in **init**
super().**init**(archive_path, logical_toc)
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 51, in **init**
self._add_from_table_of_contents(logical_toc)
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 75, in _add_from_table_of_contents
self.add(toc_entry)  # The guts of the archive.
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 364, in add
self._write_file(source, dest, type, compress=compress)
File "c:\users\алексий\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 386, in _write_file
length = os.stat(source).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь: 'C:\Users\Алексий\AppData\Local\pyinstaller\bincache00_py37_64bit\pyqt5\qtcore.pyd'

Comment: Попробуйте python embedded (это намного проще, чем приручить pyinstaller). Если нужно могу подробнее описать)

Comment: Это решается переустановкой Python в путь, где нет кириллицы